# Reading string from file: Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a file and I want to get string from that file into my javascript, so I can do something with it. I have found a way to do it, but it is little bit broken, since string from file can be really large. This is what I use now:

```
var text;
$( "#p1" ).load( "smejanje.html" );
text = $("#p1").text();
```

In html:

```
<p id="p1"> Text </p>
```

And... It works (kind of), I use intervals, stuff like that, but it seems to do the trick. But, problem is that this method sets text of p1 element to be string from file and then it gets text of p1. Is there any way to load DIRECTLY to string, without editing html element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'smejanje.html',
    dataType: 'text',
    success: function( text ) {
        alert( text );
    }
});
```

Note that if you want to do something with `text`, you need to do it inside that callback function, or you can call any function you want from there and pass `text` as a parameter, just as the code above does when it calls `alert(text)`.

Comment: I don't get it why, but when i try it, I get alert with "[object XMLDocument]" inside. Maybe .get method needs an xml file to work with?

Comment: Ah, you may be running into the "intelligent guess" that jQuery does on the downloaded data. Let's try specifying the `dataType` explicitly to be `'text'` - I updated the answer with that.

Comment: This works great! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Do like below:

```
var text;
$.get( "smejanje.html", function ( data ) {
   console.log( data );
});
```

You need to capture the output within [.get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) complete callback.

Comment: OP asked to get the value *without* loading the content into the paragraph.

Comment: Same thing as the Michael's answer, it does not work well, looks like .get needs an xml file to work with...

Comment: @НиколаПејић No its not necessary to have XML.

Comment: @thecodeparadox But, this is what I get:

http://i.imgur.com/vMCXjt9.png